# How to get GeoJSON property name in Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: geojson, google-maps-api

I would like to show the tooltip with **the unknown property name** and its **value** in Google Maps JavaScript API application. GeoJSON will be uploaded by the user and that's why property names are **unknown**. I have JS code like this:

```
map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {
      var value_name1 = ?
      var value_1 = event.feature.getProperty(PutHereDynamicValue);

      let html = value_name1 ":" value_1;
      infowindow.setContent();
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
      infowindow.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -10) });
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  }
```

How can you get dynamically from GeoJSON its **property name** and the **value**? Should I parse GeoJSON and extract properties keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out by parsing GeoJSON. Here is chunk of my code in function:

```
 var geojson = JSON.parse(geoString);
 var propert = geojson.features[0].properties;

 keys = [];
 for (var key in propert) keys.push(key);
```

So generally I parse to JSON uploaded GeoJSON, extract the "properties" keys by var property, and finally add all present keys to array "keys".

Later in tooltip code I use values from keys arrays:

```
map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {
  let html = keys[0] + " : " + event.feature.getProperty(keys[0]);
  infowindow.setContent(html);
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow.setOptions({ pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -10) });
  infowindow.open(map);
});
}
```

There is a possibility to make a loop for all keys/values here.